# python - How to input distinct random numbers into a list using loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, arraylist, random, unique

What I aim to do is to input 4 distinct numbers into a list called var. If 2 random numbers give the same number, it is not appended, and the loop iterates to pick a new random number. But my code will give only the list of random numbers that are not equal. For example if random numbers generated are 1,4,4,3 my list('var') will only have 1,4,3. ie, only 3 numbers in total. How to correct the code to append a total of 4 unique random numbers into the list?

```
import random
var=[]
end=4
for i in range(0,end,1):
 k=random.randint(0,9)
 print k
 if k not in var:
  var.append(k)
 else:
  end+=1
```

Comment: The right way to perform this action would be with random.shuffle or random.sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the requirement here is that you keep on doing that operation until your lenght of array is 4, so you can use `while len(arr) < 4`. Example coded for you :

```
import random
var=[]
end=4
while len(var) < end:
 k=random.randint(0,9)
 print k
 if k not in var:
  var.append(k)
```

A better way to do this would be `random.sample`

```
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(range(0, 9), 4) # xrange is using python 2.7
```

Read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample).